# Playing audio on different devices?

Tags: audio, python-sounddevice

I have a USB headphones connected to system. So now my system has two different audio output devices (one internal speakers and other is USB headphone). Though it is possible t choose the default the output device. What i am interested is play different audio on each of the device at the same time. In other words i am looking for a program solution which gives freedom to choose the device on which the audio should be played. By any means, using any library is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [sounddevice.play()](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sounddevice.play), you can simply specify the desired `device` with each call.

You can either use the device ID (e.g. `device=3`) or a substring of the device name (e.g. `device='headphone'`, if that's part of the device name).

You can get a list of devices with:

```
python3 -m sounddevice
```

Comment: Hey! Would something like this work with two sets of Bluetooth headphones?